# Meaning of "Thanks for your insights"?

Tags: meaning

What does "Thanks for your insights" mean?

And how should I use this sentence?

Answer (score 7):

"Insight" is an understanding of something.  So when someone says "thank you for your insight", it means they are grateful for the understanding that they've provided.

It's also a very dry way to thank someone for helpful advice, and can be used sarcastically if the 'insight' being provided is not very helpful.

Either way you use it,  it's a phrase and a full sentence in itself, so it can be used as a stand-alone statement (Thank you for your insight.), or as part of a larger sentence (Thank you for your insight, it was very helpful).

Comment: +1 for noting that this phrase _can_ easily be used sarcastically (even if it isn't necessarily always so used), since it doesn't really say anything about the _nature_ of the insight provided. It could mean "insight into the issue at hand", or it might mean "insight into how a crazy person may see the issue". In that way it's similar to, say "with all due respect", which, while a common form of polite address, doesn't _actually_ say anything about the amount of respect the speaker believes is due.